# How to change color of picker's underline?

Tags: forms, xamarin, picker

I write application in Xamarin Forms. I have made "entry" underline color as transparent using custom renderers. I need also to set color of bottom line of picker to transparent in the same way, but it is not working. I have done an example from here: https://alexdunn.org/2017/07/24/xamarin-tip-borderless-picker/ and set Control.BackgroundColor to transparent but it has no effect. In Xamarin.Android styles.xml there is accent color to change but it is changing only color of bottom line when it is tapped and it has affect to all application (that is bad). Regular black color of underline remains. Is there any other solution or is it  better give up with Xamarin Forms's picker and create own custom pop up?

Comment: I have installed Rg.Plugins.Popup and made my own pop up. Easier way than fighting with custom renderer of picker, which doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CustomRenderer** .

#### in iOS

```
using System;
using App1.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(MyiOSPicker))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
    public class MyiOSPicker : PickerRenderer, IUIPickerViewDelegate, IUIPickerViewDataSource
    {

        string SelectedValue;

        public MyiOSPicker()
        {

        }

        public nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return Element.Items.Count;
        }

        [Export("pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:")]
        public UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
        {


            foreach(UIView line in pickerView.Subviews)
            {
                if(line.Frame.Height<1)
                {
                    line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;   // set line coloer here!!!!
                }
            }

            UILabel label = new UILabel
            {
                //here you can set the style of item!!!

                TextColor = UIColor.Blue,

                Text = Element.Items[(int)row].ToString(),

                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,

            };
            return label;
        }


        [Export("pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:")]
        public void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            Control.Text = Element.Items[(int)row];
            SelectedValue = Element.Items[(int)row];
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                SelectedValue = Element.Items[0];

                UIPickerView pickerView = (UIPickerView)Control.InputView;
                pickerView.WeakDelegate = this;
                pickerView.DataSource = this;


                UIToolbar toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;

                UIBarButtonItem done = new UIBarButtonItem("Done", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (object sender, EventArgs click) =>
                {
                    Control.Text = SelectedValue;
                    toolbar.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    pickerView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                });
                toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { done };
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

#### in Android

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Lang.Reflect;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using App1.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(MyAndroidPicker))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
    public class MyAndroidPicker : PickerRenderer
    {
        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        private AlertDialog _dialog;

        public MyAndroidPicker(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            Control.Click += Control_Click;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        private void SetPickerDividerColor(TextColorNumberPicker picker)
        {
            Field[] fields = picker.Class.GetDeclaredFields();

            foreach (Field pf in fields)
            {
                

                if (pf.Name.Equals("mSelectionDivider"))
                {
                    pf.Accessible = true;
                    // set the line color here!!!
                    pf.Set(picker, new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow));

                }
            }

        }


        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Picker model = Element;

            var picker = new TextColorNumberPicker(Context);
            if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
            {

                picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
                picker.MinValue = 0;
              //  picker.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
                picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());

                //call the method after you setting DisplayedValues
                
                picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
                picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;

                SetPickerDividerColor(picker);
            }

            var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.AddView(picker);

            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
            builder.SetView(layout);

            builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
            builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel  ", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                _dialog = null;
            });
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok ", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
                // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }
                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
            {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            };
            _dialog.Show();
        }

    }

    public class TextColorNumberPicker: NumberPicker
    {
      public TextColorNumberPicker(Context context) : base(context)
      {

      }

      public override void AddView(Android.Views.View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams @params)
      {
        base.AddView(child, index, @params);
        UpdateView(child);
      }

      public void UpdateView(Android.Views.View view)
      {
        if ( view is EditText ) {

            //set the font of text
            ((EditText)view).TextSize = 12;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

And you can also set other style as you want .

Answer (score 1):

The underlying component that is used for the Picker on Android is an EditText, and so the easiest way to style the Picker is to style the EditText in the Android projects `style.xml` (versus a custom renderer that does a similar thing, but might be more extensive than such a simple change) just like one would style an EditText if working only in Android. The underline in Android is there because the default Android Edit Text (for "Material Design App Compat" at the time of writing) is a "Drawable" with that underline. Unfortunately, I cannot figure what color is used for the underline when the edit text is not active but here is the gist:

`style.xml`:

```xml
<style>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
      <!-- colorAccent is the color used for the underline bar when the edit field is active -->
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
      <item name="colorNotActive?">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

Note that changing the `style.xml` in with Xamarin.Forms and VS 2022 often requires some combo of a restart of VS 2022\a clean of the project\or unload and reload of the project in order to get things to build again. The tooling is notorious for such "features".
Likewise I would spend more time figuring out the item name but I would need to fire up an Android Studio project because its takes so long to tweak in Xamrin.Forms...

You can also change the entire background ->

Example, one can change the background of the EditText like so it looks like a form field:

`style.xml`:

```xml
<style>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
      <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item>
</style>
```

[There is a handy table of Xamarin.Forms Components (renderers) to the actual Native Components that are used (iOS, Android, UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers)